# Right Triangle Within a Rectangle, Hypotenuse Shares Entire Side of Rectangle and Third Point Intersects Rectangle Opposite Side

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, rectangles

I know the Length (L) and Width (W) of a rectangle is 8 and 3.5 meters respectively.

Triangle ABL is a right triangle, therefore angle AB is 90-degrees.

L = C + D = 8

W will fall within this range: 0 < W <= L/2; I'll assume W = 3.5 for this math.

I need to solve for A, B, C and D.

I'm stuck, I don't know why, likely stress and lack of sleep, but I'm stuck. If you can offer help I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: It's impossible. This rectangle does not exist: Take a circle with diameter $L$.

Comment: No, I'm certain this is possible, I've updated the picture to hopefully make it more clear. Let's assume the angles were 30-60-90 degrees, you could easily have 3 such triangles of different sizes make up a larger rectangle. I know the Width (W) and the Lenght (L) for the rectangle, I just don't know what the angle is that would be required to make all 3 puzzle pieces work together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT1:

The semi-circle that contains right triangle cuts the lower side of rectangle, since height is less than radius. Construction below :

By symmetry $(A,B)$ and so $(C,D)$ can be interchanged.

Pythagoras theorem and height of right triangle
$$A^2+B^2=L^2\,;\,\dfrac{1}{W^2}=\dfrac{1}{A^2}+\dfrac{1}{B^2} \,;$$

You must commit to memory the second formula if not already done so; (it is often useful in geometrical calculation of right triangles). Solve the quadratic equation getting:

$$ (2 A^2,2 B^2)=L^2\pm \sqrt{L^4-4L^2W^2};\,$$
$$ C^2=A^2-W^2;\, D^2=B^2-W^2;\, $$

[image]

Evaluate them for given $(L,W)$ as

$$(A,B,C,D) \approx (6.89144,4.06301,5.93649,2.06351),\,$$
and
$$(A,B,C,D) \approx (4.06301,6.89144,2.06351,5.93649).\,$$

Comment: Thank you for the picture, this really helped me. A small correction to what you documented, W can be any positive number that is <= L/2. I really appreciate the assistance from you and others.

Comment: Glad it helped. For $W=L/2$ the situation is tangential, so $A=B,C=D$. Since you gave half length $3.5<4$ as rectangle width/height in the question I left out the general case on purpose that may not be instructive.

Comment: For. Tangent case  $A=B=L/\sqrt{2};C=D=L/2\,$

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$A^2+B^2 = L^2,\>\>\>\>\> AB = WL$$

Assume $A>B$. Then,

$$A-B = \sqrt{A^2+B^2 -2AB} = \sqrt{L^2 -2WL} $$
$$A+B = \sqrt{A^2+B^2 + 2AB} = \sqrt{L^2 +2WL} $$

which yield the solutions for $A$ and $B$,

$$A = \frac {1}2 \left(\sqrt{L^2 +2WL}+\sqrt{L^2 -2WL}\right)$$
$$B = \frac {1}2 \left(\sqrt{L^2 +2WL}-\sqrt{L^2 -2WL}\right)$$

Also, note that

$$C+D = L, \>\>\>\>\>CD = W^2$$

So, $C$ and $D$ satisfy the quadratic equation

$$x^2 -Lx+W^2=0$$

which yields,

$$C = \frac12(L+\sqrt{L^2-4W^2}), \>\>\>\>\>\>D = \frac12(L-\sqrt{L^2-4W^2})$$

Comment: Thank you for your reply, except for the part about being "Ill-defined". I do get what you are saying is 0 < W <= L/2.  So assuming the number is within that range, can you help me with how to define A B C and D? I'll update my original question to get rid of the 5.  Thanks again for the assistance.

Comment: @MarkMain - please see the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for the kind reply. I believe your answer assumes that W will equal L/2, in this case, 4, am I correct? But I can see that it's possible for W to equal any number from greater than zero up to and equalling L/2, all having right triangles with the hypotenuse being on the L side of the rectangle. What if W equals 3.5 for example?

Comment: @MarkMain - the results derived are general. You can plug in any value of $W\in (0,\frac L2)$ to evaluate A,B, C and D.

Answer (score 1):

According to your data you have a right triangle of hypotenusa $8$ and height $5$ so you can calculate the legs $A, B$ from the system
$$AB=8\cdot5\space \text{(areas)}\\A^2+B^2=64\space \text{(Pythagoras)}$$

You can verify solving the system it has no real solutions or, easier, plotting the hyperbola $xy=40$ and the circle $x^2+y^2=64$ so you can see there are no common points.

Comment: But I can have this: 0 < W <= L/2, correct? And so assuming W is within that range, let's assume 3.5 for W, how do I calculate A, B, C and D?

Comment: In this new case you have  $xy=28$ and $x^2+y^2=64$  so you can deduce, for example, $x^2+y^2+2xy=64+56=120$ lo que da $x+y=2\sqrt{30}$ and similarly $x^2+y^2-2xy=64-56=8$ so $x-y=2\sqrt2$. This gives you the $x,y$ positive you need. (theoretically your system has two other $(x,y)$ with $x,y$ negative which by the natuire of your problem you have to discard).

Comment: Thank you for the kind reply. would it not be 64 + 12.25 + 56 = 132.25? And I got lost with the product of 2 to the square root of 30.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: You have $\sqrt{120}=2\sqrt{30}$ and $\sqrt8=2\sqrt2$

Answer (score 1):

As long as $W \lt \frac L2$ there is a solution.  If you draw a semicircle with $L$ the diameter it shows the points where there will be a right angle.  Where the semicircle intersects the lower edge of the window is the point you want.  $AWC$, $BDW$ and $ABL$ are similar triangles.

I get the equations 
$$c^2+3.5^2=a^2\\
d^2+3.5^2=b^2\\
a^2+b^2=8^2\\
c+d=8$$
Which [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=c%5E2%2B3.5%5E2%3Da%5E2%2Cd%5E2%2B3.5%5E2%3Db%5E2%2Ca%5E2%2Bb%5E2%3D64%2Cc%2Bd%3D8) gives a solution 
$$a≈4.06301, b≈6.89144, c≈2.06351, d≈5.93649$$